# Get error java.io.IOException: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: java

I use `hidapi-jni.dll/hidapi-jni.so` and write program in Java to read and write data to my device. My device defined as a HID device. My code run very well on linux (Debian 7.1) and I can read and write data from/to device. But on Windows (Windows 7 and XP) I can only read data and when try to write I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: The parameter is incorrect.
```

One part of Write method is:

```
try {
     HIDManager hid_mgr = HIDManager.getInstance();
     dev = hid_mgr.openById(VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID, null);
     byte[] by = new byte[4];
     by[0] = (byte) 1;
     by[1] = (byte) 2;
     by[2] = (byte) 3;
     by[3] = (byte) 4;
     dev.write(by);
     } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ne) {
     System.err.println(ne);
     }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Start by not hiding the exception stack trace. Don't catch the exception if you can't handle it. Or at least, print its stack trace using `ne.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Make sure your byte order is the same in the different systems. I know there is a difference between windows and unix. Since you are down at the byte level, you may need to reverse the byte order in your code based on the OS. I would throw a System.out.println() in the code to print the value of the bytes, then compare the output from each system.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my error.
in windows the first byte will be 0. then my code is:

```
by[0] = 0;
```

and if i write via

```
dev.write(by);
```

work correctly.

Answer (score -2):

@Hassan Amiri : Basically Linux converts addresses into values and writing But seriously windows does correct .. Use Foreach loop for ur array and after that write the data .

```
try {
     HIDManager hid_mgr = HIDManager.getInstance();
     dev = hid_mgr.openById(VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID, null);
     byte[] by = new byte[4];
     by[0] = (byte) 1;
     by[1] = (byte) 2;
     by[2] = (byte) 3;
     by[3] = (byte) 4;
   for(byte b : by){  dev.write(b);}}
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: (Not the downvoter) "But seriously windows does correct" Aside from the bad grammar, it sounds like you're contradicting what the poster said regarding Windows, without saying anything about why how he did it is wrong, and why your way is the correct way.

Comment: Then *say* that you got the issue before when you wrote out the entire array, but no longer had issues when you wrote it out byte by byte. If you hold that back, someone just glancing at what you say would think that you're just throwing something random out there and hoping that it's right.

Comment: @Hi Luckyman Nevermore!!!
In hidapi-jni method `write` get array of `byte` and if send a `byte` get error.

    write(byte[] by)

Comment: Yes. Stack trace of error code is:    
java.io.IOException: The parameter is incorrect.
 at com.codeminders.hidapi.HIDDevice.write(Native Method)
 at PKGMain.HIDAPI.readDevice(HIDAPI.java:133)
 at PKGMain.HIDAPI.connectDevice(HIDAPI.java:43)
 at PKGMain.DriverClass.run(DriverClass.java:7)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: @HassanAmiri hey hassan .. i have many questions here dude .. as i dnt knw abt ur project .. see .. first point is why ur type casting 1 to byte again .. u can directly use byte by[0] =1; secondly try to add byte object (trail and error process ..) .. like byte b = new byte(1); remove all parameters and add only one parameter only .. as i dnt knw the project .. try to analyize the situation ..BYE

Comment: @Luckyman Nevermore. Dear Luckyman Nevermore i casting byte because i simple code for test to find error and i forget to delete casting(Excuse me). I test to write one byte (byte[] b = new byte[1]) and have error. i test to write one byte on linux and work correctly. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @HassanAmiri hey hassan .. Just please test the above steps for me .. just take or copy the complied class of windows and replace it into linux and deploy the application .. similarly do vice versa for windows ..If second situation doesnt work still ,den der r changes of code w.r.t java version , OS .. please check and ask me again if u didn't understand the situation